# Causal mediation effect decomposition when you have multiple mediators

Tags: causality, mediation

Suppose we have outcome variable $Y,$ one treatment $T,$ and two
mediator variables, $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}.$ We write the structural
model as:
$$
Y=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}T+\beta_{2}M_{1}+\beta_{3}M_{2}+\epsilon
$$
$$
M_{1}=\alpha+\alpha_{1}T+v
$$
$$
M_{2}=\gamma+\gamma_{1}T+e
$$
Here, the direct effect of $T$ is straightforward, which is $\beta_{1}$.
Is the total effect $\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}\alpha_{1}+\gamma_{1}\beta_{3}?$
Also, is the causal medion effect is for $M_{1}$ given $\beta_{2}\alpha_{1}$
while that for $M_{2}$ given as $\gamma_{1}\beta_{3}?$ Does it make
sense to have two different mediation effects here?

Comment: Can you please define: i) "total effect"; ii) "causal medion effect"?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the model that you have specified you are correct

- Direct effect: $\beta_1$
- Indirect effect through $M_1$: $\alpha_1\cdot \beta_2$
- Indirect effect through $M_2$: $\gamma_1\cdot \beta_3$

It makes sense to decompose the indirect effect into a component that is due to each of the 2 mediators. The total indirect effect would be $\alpha_1\cdot \beta_2+\gamma_1\cdot \beta_3$

A detailed introduction to this decomposition can be found in [Vanderweele 2014](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4287269/), which also describes how to incorporate a potential $M_1\cdot M_2$ interaction